# Function creating assertion failure

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a function that will delete an item from an array of structs. When I enter a number (scanf("%d", num)), I get a pop-up saying I have an assertion failure and to abort the program. There was a warning on the indicated line below, but it didn't stop the program from compiling. When the program crashes the error appears on the same line:

```
void delete_stud(Student* s, int lsize)
{

    int num = 0;

    printf("What number student in the list would you like to delete?\nStudent number: ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    // This line ^^^

    if (num <= lsize) {

        for (int i = num; i <= lsize; i++) {

            s[i - 1] = s[i];
        }

        lsize--;
    }
    else {

        printf("Invalid value entered\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I call the function with:

```
delete_stud(class_list, lsize);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you move over to using `iostream` input and output will be simpler and less error prone. You are currently doing input and output the `c` way.

Comment: A `<=` in a for loop is often a sign of an off-by-one mistake. Check the range of the index variable and make sure it remains in the bounds of valid indexes for `s`

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Note the ampersand.